# The keyboard does not hide with two UITextField with one who calls a picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I have two UITexfield, one normal and a second who calls my custom picker. The problem is, when I put text in my first UITextfield and after I tap on my second for call the picker, the keyboard doesn't Hide.

My code:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField.tag == 5) {//UITextField who call picker
        [tfNumber resignFirstResponder];
        [tfDate resignFirstResponder];

        datePicker = [[ANDatePickerView alloc]initWithSuperView:self.view delegate:self];
        [datePicker appears];
    } 
}
```

The picker appears bellow the keyboard.

Where is de problem ?

Comment: Please set delegate for both textField. and set code in below method
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{ // your code }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
     - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
        {
          if (textField.tag == 5)
          {
   datePicker = [[ANDatePickerView alloc]initWithSuperView:self.view delegate:self];
        [datePicker appears];
           return NO;

          }
          return YES;
        }
```

Comment: Works when I put
datePicker = [[ANDatePickerView alloc]initWithSuperView:self.view delegate:self];
        [datePicker appears];
in the if

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the end of the method that shows your pickerView;

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```